# Failed to run RemoteMessage

Tags: java

```
package Service;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.ablut.yummycakesug.MainActivity;
import com.ablut.yummycakesug.R;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                .setContentText(notification.getBody())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager noti =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        noti.notify(0,builder.build());
    }
}
```

## And the error as follows

> 

C:\Users\ABDULSALAAM\AndroidStudioProjects\YummyCakesUG3\app\src\main\java\Service\MyFirebaseMessaging.java:26: error: cannot access zza
RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
^
class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found"RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification(); "                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                       )

Comment: Maybe i need to improve something in the code

Comment: Especially when running the emulator